# Can two or more queries be executed at the very same time?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

Ok, let's say we have `bank_account` table. There is a row called `money`. It has 2,000 value. And we have two persons trying to withdraw that money, let's suppose they can do it. So, is it possible that they would do it at the same time? For example. there is a made-up code:

```
 $all_money = get_value('money', 'bank_account); //lets suppose thats a function how we get value money from bank_account table

 if($all_money > 0) 
 {
     //here is a code where those money are being withdrawed from bank_account and inserting into the person's account
 }
```

If those two persons get value 2,000 at the same time then it means this clause `if($all_money > 0)` will be executed and both players will get 2,000 and bank_account will have -2,000 value of money. So, is it possible to happen? If yes, then how could I protect it? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute this before accessing the table:

```
LOCK TABLE table_name READ;
```

That will lock the table. When you have finished doing the work, you call:

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to belief, SQL statements are received and placed in a queue for processing.  They are not executed at the same time.

What happens depends on business rules - if a bank account allows overdraft, the second request will succeed (assuming large enough overdraft).  Otherwise, the second request will fail.

Comment: +1 I would give you plus 2 for your name if I could...best.name.ever!

Comment: I should mention that Isolation Levels can complicate things - the default allows for priority to SELECT, meaning checking your balance could return the value before a withdrawl is made.

Comment: "[SQL statements] are not executed at the same time"? Do you want to further qualify this statements? Are you saying there is never any overlapping in the execution of any SQL statements? I hope not.

Answer (score 2):

I think one approach would be to use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). When the transactions starts the table will get locked. Its actually similar to what Cristian proposed.

Comment: Really? I actually use transactions and these are the great news if it's correct and somebody can approve that.

Comment: I am not sure if it does. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way at all.  I think your correct choice is Cristian C's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions in innodb will help you with that. Remember to read up on your mysql version, because they were bugged earlier.

Answer (score 1):

A **very** stereotypical example would be:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE do_banktransfer(
  IN transfer_amount INT,
  IN from_account    INT,
  IN to_account      INT,
  OUT success        INT)
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE account SET balance = balance - transfer_amount WHERE id = from_account;
UPDATE account SET balance = balance + transfer_amount WHERE id = to_account;
SELECT balance INTO cur_balance FROM account WHERE id = from_account;
IF cur_balance < 0 THEN
    SET success = 0;
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE 
    SET success = 1;
    COMMIT;
END IF;
END;//
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are worried about 2 separate threads connecting to the database and one with-drawing money while the other is executing code that based on a balance read previously.

In this situation you should apply a read lock (as Christian says) prior to querying the balance and releasing the lock once [in your code snippet] the if statement has ended.

You may face problems if anything falls over while your thread still has the lock so you need some canny bash scripts to kill stuff ;)